# A reference to the procedure in the database

Tags: c#, linq

I have a REST API which in one endpoint refers to the procedure in the SQL Server database.

Currently, it references the procedure using `DataTable` and `SqlConnection`.

**I want to use LINQ to refer to the procedure. How to do it?**

The procedure has about 600 lines of code, so I guess you probably can not rewrite it for `LINQ`.

Ultimately, the transition to LINQ was to ensure the possibility of using another database. With the procedure it will rather be impossible. Any advice in this situation is welcome.

Comment: Which flavor of LINQ? LinqToSql, LinqToEF, LinqToObjects over `DataTable`?

Comment: @TanveerBadar I make other queries on Entities using LINQ Lambda. But will it help with procedures? Can you suggest different variants? At this stage, everything is still flexible

Comment: You can simply call procedure by using dbContext.proceduerName(parameters...);

Comment: @TanveerBadar You forgot Linq2nHibernate and Linq2OData.

Comment: Is your "procedure" a UDF/ Table UDF or Stored Proc? With Stored Proc, you can map your Stored Proc to a Entity Framework function. Depending on if you are using Code First or Database First, the way you import it into your edmx is different.

Comment: @Aron Stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your procedure is returning some rows, here's one way to do it through EF.

`var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>("exec your_procedure_nanme");`

I cannot give you more specifics because your question is pretty open-ended and leaves a lot to assumptions.

Comment: There is no method like `.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>`. Error: `'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery'`

Comment: Now is `dbContext.Query<ResultType>().FromSql("exec your_procedure_name");`